# StaleDataException:Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter

In my application, I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter to update Listviews. This SimpleCursorAdapter takes data from Cursor object. Here when I close cursor in onCreate method then it's throwing **StaleDataException:Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed**. but when *I removed this close method on cursor then it didn't happen and it worked well*.But if we remove close method on cursor then will it not create memory leakage?

With cursor.close() -

```
//the columns which we want to show in list view
    private static final String[] columnsToUse = new String[]{
            UserDictionary.Words.WORD,
            UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY};

    // array of item ids where above two entries will be saved
    private static final int[] toView = new int[]{
            android.R.id.text1,
            android.R.id.text2};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //TextView displayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);

        ListView dictionaryList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_view);

        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();



        SimpleCursorAdapter dictionaryAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                cursor, columnsToUse, toView, 0);

        dictionaryList.setAdapter(dictionaryAdapter);
        cursor.close();
```

throwing - StaleDataException:Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed

but if I comment this cursor.close() then this error doesn't come -

```
   //the columns which we want to show in list view
        private static final String[] columnsToUse = new String[]{
                UserDictionary.Words.WORD,
                UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY};

        // array of item ids where above two entries will be saved
        private static final int[] toView = new int[]{
                android.R.id.text1,
                android.R.id.text2};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //TextView displayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_text);

            ListView dictionaryList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_view);

            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();



            SimpleCursorAdapter dictionaryAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    cursor, columnsToUse, toView, 0);

            dictionaryList.setAdapter(dictionaryAdapter);
           // cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `Cursor.close()` does [releases all of its resources and making it completely invalid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close%28%29)**...** if you call `Cursor.close()` right after the adapter what will the `CursorAdapter` use?

To solve it,

`close()` your `Cursor` in `onDestroy()` or when the `listView` along with the `CursorAdapter` will no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that:

The system resources required to draw your UI should be freed as soon as the UI of the activity is no longer in focus. Since this happens after `onStop()` is called you should prepared for freeing up resources as soon as onStop.

> So use `onStop()` instead of `onDestroy()` method to close the cursor.